# How to find the smallest value by using Lagrange multiplicators?

Tags: functions, optimization

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive constants. How one can find the smallest value of
the sum of three numbers $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ at the surface

$\dfrac{a}{x_1}+\frac{b}{x_2}+\frac{c}{x_3}=1$

by using Lagrange multiplicators

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: Hi, I knew about the Lagrange multiplicators only for the case when we have given some kind of constraint but this is the new case for me that is why I put this case here to get the peoples views on such cases and get help to solve such problems.

Comment: This is not convex, so I'll remove that tag for you.

Answer (score 0):

Put

$$H(x,y,z,\lambda)=x+y+z+\lambda\left(\frac ax+\frac by+\frac cz-1\right):$$

$$\begin{align*}H'_x&=1-\frac{a\lambda}{x^2}=0\iff a\lambda=x^2\\
H'_x&=1-\frac{b\lambda}{y^2}=0\iff b\lambda=y^2\\
H'_x&=1-\frac{c\lambda}{z^2}=0\iff c\lambda=z^2\\
H_\lambda'&=\frac ax+\frac by+\frac cz-1=0\end{align*}$$

and from here it follows

$$\frac{x^2}a=\frac{y^2}b=\frac{z^2}c$$

Continue from here.

Editing to address OP's doubt: look to $\;H_\lambda'\;$ and the last equation above:

$$y=\sqrt\frac ba\,x\;,\;\;z=\sqrt\frac ca\,x\implies$$

$$1=\frac ax+\frac by+\frac cz=\frac ax+\frac{\sqrt{ab}}x+\frac{\sqrt{ac}}x=1\implies x=\sqrt a\left(\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c\right)\implies$$

$$\lambda=\frac{x^2}a=\left(\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c\right)^2$$

Try to take it from here.

Comment: You have eliminated $\laymda$ how we will then find the value of this $\laymda$ as we need it for our solution?

Comment: He has given you $\lambda$: it's the common value of that last equality. So finding any of $\{x,y,z\}$ will give you $\lambda.$